# Can I make Lightroom see existing Flickr albums as photosets

Tags: lightroom, flickr

I have started using Lightroom5 and I generally organize my photos by location. So if I have taken some photos for a new location I create a new photoset (i.e Liverpool) drag my images to it and publish, they are then all created in a new Flickr album.

Hoewever I have been using Flickr for a number of years, is there a way to let know Lightroom know about existing albums and get Lightroom to list them as photosets. So for example i have an album called 'Manchester', I have recently taken some new Manchester photos and would want them added to this existing album in Flickr, but there is no photoset listed for that album.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you create a new photoset in Lightroom, it will be named Photoset by default. Publishing like this, it will create a new album on Flickr.

Creating a new photoset and **renaming it to the same name an existing album has on Flickr**, LR will realize the album is already there on Flickr and publish to that album. It will not realize that there are already pictures in the album. You can still use it to publish/upload new pictures though.

Note that you need to rename exactly as it is on Flickr, including spaces and other characters.

I've done this just now with the most current LR 5.4 and a free Flickr account.

Comment: Can confirm this still works on LR6